# When try to call a Python function the main where I call restart

Tags: python, multithreading

I've a problem with my Python code: when I call the function from another class, the class where I am calling the function restart, and the compiler gives this error message:

```
RuntimeError: 
    An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
    current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

The class where I launch the code is this:

```
 finestre = creatore_finestre()
    print(finestre[0])
```

The code of the function is:

```
DIR_DATA = '../../../data/'
SIGNALS_INDEX = {
    'HR': 0,
    'ABPSys': 1,
    'ABPDias': 2,
    'ABPMean': 3,
    'CVP': 4,
    'PULSE': 5,
    'RESP': 6,
    'SpO2': 7,
    'NBPSys': 8,
    'NBPDias': 9,
    'NBPMean': 10,
}


def download_information_database(id_patient):
    wfdb.dldatabase('mimic2db/numerics', DIR_DATA + id_patient, records=[id_patient])


def create_csv(id_patient, signal):

    # Download the patient information
    download_information_database(id_patient)

    # Firstly, we read the patient information
    patient_dir = DIR_DATA + id_patient + "/"
    record = wfdb.rdsamp(patient_dir + id_patient, channels=[SIGNALS_INDEX[signal]])


    # We calculate the datetime base
    date_str = record.basedate + ' ' + record.basetime
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

    # We read the signal values
    signal = record.p_signals

    # We write the csv file
    with open(patient_dir + id_patient + '.csv', 'w+') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',lineterminator="\n")

        for s in signal:
            date = date + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

            if not math.isnan(float(s)):
                writer.writerow([date.strftime("'[%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y]'"),str(int(s[0]) * 1000)])




def creatore_finestre():

    #Open the file of information for each patients
    in_file = open("../../../data/CodePatientsTraining.csv", "r+")
    lettore_file = csv.reader(in_file)
    #Create dictionary of list
    finestre = defaultdict(list)
    for nomeFile in lettore_file:
        print(nomeFile[0])
        create_csv(nomeFile[0],"ABPMean")
        f = open("../../../data/" + nomeFile[0] + "/" + nomeFile[0] + ".csv", "r+")
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        line = in_file.readline()
        lista = list(reader)
        i = 0
        for timestamp in lista:
            if (timestamp[0] != nomeFile[1]):
                i += 1
            else:
                print(timestamp[0], nomeFile[1], i)
                break

        decade = 0
        somma = 0
        arrivo = 1
        minute = 10
        while (i != 0):
            i -= 1
            if (lista[i][1] != '0' and lista[i][1] != '-' and int(lista[i][1]) > 0):
                somma += float(lista[i][1])
                decade += 1
            if (decade == minute):
                f = SlidingWindows((somma / minute), nomeFile[4])
                finestre[arrivo].append(f)
                print("T[" + str(arrivo) + "]:")
                for value in finestre[arrivo]:
                    print(value)
                decade = 0
                arrivo += 1
                somma = 0

    return finestre
```

My idea is to create a SlidingWindows for each CSV file in the function, and take all the sliding windows from the other class.

Comment: That exception is a `multiprocessing` related one, but the code you've shown doesn't appear to use `multiprocessing` anywhere. Is it in `SlidingWindows` somewhere? In any case, as the exception message says, the way to fix the issue is usually to put your top-level main module code into an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block  so that it won't be run again in the child processes.

Comment: The code of SlidingWindows contains only costructor and toString.
Yeah If I try to make a main in the principal module, I don't have this problem, but I need to use in other class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import your_module
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    extractor = your_Module.your_function()
    extractor.runInParallel(numProcesses=2, numThreads=4)
```

Comment: You need to protect the main code like this to avoid creating subprocesses recursively, because  on Windows the subprocesses will execute the main module at the start.

Comment: I have solved creating a process inside the class where i have need, but not using a parallel, but a simple process like this:

`p = Process(creatore_finestre())`

Comment: How I can obtain the return from the process p?

Comment: p = Process(creatore_finestre())  then do  p.wait()  and  out = p.join()  , the return value is collected in out

Comment: I have tried, but it give me this error:
`File "C:\Users\Donato\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 73, in __init__
    assert group is None, 'group argument must be None for now'
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now`

Comment: p = Process(target=creatore_finestre())

Comment: I think that the defaultdict it's not possbile to return from the join

`Process Process-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Donato\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Donato\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object is not callable
None`